# Learning web scraping - Selenium gives constant "NoSuchElementException" errors. I've tried everything I can think of

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [the IFSC website](https://www.ifsc-climbing.org/index.php/world-competition/calendar?task=ranking-complete&category=3) to scrape all of the climbers names, countries, and points. I thought I could do this with BeautifulSoup, but I was having so many issues that I tried Selenium... now I'm having a bunch of issues with this, and I'm starting to go a little insane.

I've followed every tutorial I can, and I've looked at the documentation and [how to locate elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), but regardless of how I try to search for an element, Selenium throws that exception. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I do know that there is JavaScript on the page, but I don't know what to do with it or how to extract data from it.

Below is what I'm seeing when I inspect the webpage:

[image: inspector]

and below is the code I'm trying to use:

```py
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "https://www.ifsc-climbing.org/index.php/world-competition/calendar?task=ranking-complete&category=3"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

climbers = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution my friend, I hope you'll appreciate it.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.ifsc-climbing.org/index.php/world-competition/calendar?task=ranking-complete&category=3')
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.frame("calendar")
table_wrapper = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="table_id_wrapper"]')
results = table_wrapper.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

data = []
for result in results:
    details = result.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    temp_dict = {
        "name": f"{details[1].text} {details[2].text}",
        "country": details[3].text,
        "points": details[4].text
    }
    data.append(temp_dict)

print(data)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'YOSHIYUKI OGATA', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '4535.0'}, {'name': 'TOMOA NARASAKI', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '3680.0'}, {'name': 'KOKORO FUJII', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '3370.0'}, {'name': 'YANNICK FLOHÉ', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '2526.0'}, {'name': 'MAXIMILLIAN MILNE', 'country': 'GBR', 'points': '2475.0'}, {'name': 'MEJDI SCHALCK', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '2459.0'}, {'name': 'DOHYUN LEE', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '2151.5'}, {'name': 'JONGWON CHON', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '2072.5'}, {'name': 'COLIN DUFFY', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '1976.0'}, {'name': 'PAUL JENFT', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '1799.5'}, {'name': 'REI KAWAMATA', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '1774.5'}, {'name': 'JAKOB SCHUBERT', 'country': 'AUT', 'points': '1740.0'}, {'name': 'ANZE PEHARC', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '1709.0'}, {'name': 'NICOLAI UZNIK', 'country': 'AUT', 'points': '1615.0'}, {'name': 'KEITA DOHI', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '1481.5'}, {'name': 'TOMOAKI TAKATA', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '1269.0'}, {'name': 'YUJI INOUE', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '1118.66'}, {'name': 'SEAN BAILEY', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '1063.5'}, {'name': 'HAMISH MCARTHUR', 'country': 'GBR', 'points': '1048.5'}, {'name': 'MEICHI NARASAKI', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '1040.0'}, {'name': 'SAM AVEZOU', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '983.5'}, {'name': 'ROSS FULKERSON', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '969.0'}, {'name': 'ALEXANDER MEGOS', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '889.0'}, {'name': 'GREGOR VEZONIK', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '807.0'}, {'name': 'MAX KLEESATTEL', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '788.0'}, {'name': 'MICKAEL MAWEM', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '741.5'}, {'name': 'ALBERTO GINÉS LÓPEZ', 'country': 'ESP', 'points': '627.33'}, {'name': 'JAN-LUCA POSCH', 'country': 'AUT', 'points': '599.0'}, {'name': 'ZAN LOVENJAK SUDAR', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '597.0'}, {'name': 'SATONE YOSHIDA', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '550.5'}, {'name': 'KENTO YAMAGUCHI', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '530.0'}, {'name': 'ALEX KHAZANOV', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '517.5'}, {'name': 'MANUEL CORNU', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '498.0'}, {'name': 'VICTOR BAUDRAND', 'country': 'CAN', 'points': '475.0'}, {'name': 'BENJAMIN HANNA', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '432.66'}, {'name': 'NATHAN PHILLIPS', 'country': 'GBR', 'points': '419.5'}, {'name': 'JERNEJ KRUDER', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '392.5'}, {'name': 'NIMROD MARCUS', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '387.83'}, {'name': 'ZACH GALLA', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '377.0'}, {'name': 'SIMON LORENZI', 'country': 'BEL', 'points': '373.0'}, {'name': 'MATHIEU TERNANT', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '340.0'}, {'name': 'CHRISTOPH SCHWEIGER', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '330.0'}, {'name': 'GUY MCNAMEE', 'country': 'CAN', 'points': '328.0'}, {'name': 'SASCHA LEHMANN', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '299.16'}, {'name': 'PHILIPP MARTIN', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '275.0'}, {'name': 'SEAN MCCOLL', 'country': 'CAN', 'points': '251.5'}, {'name': 'GHOLAMALI BARATZADEH', 'country': 'IRI', 'points': '204.5'}, {'name': 'SIMON HIBBELER', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '200.0'}, {'name': 'MICHAEL PICCOLRUAZ', 'country': 'ITA', 'points': '196.5'}, {'name': 'ADAM ONDRA', 'country': 'CZE', 'points': '194.0'}, {'name': 'SUNGSU LEE', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '191.5'}, {'name': 'CHARLES BARRON', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '174.0'}, {'name': 'KATSURA KONISHI', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '168.0'}, {'name': 'NIKOLAY RUSEV', 'country': 'BUL', 'points': '164.0'}, {'name': 'NICOLAS COLLIN', 'country': 'BEL', 'points': '157.5'}, {'name': 'ALEX WATERHOUSE', 'country': 'GBR', 'points': '155.5'}, {'name': 'EDVARDS GRUZITIS', 'country': 'LAT', 'points': '146.5'}, {'name': 'TAISEI ISHIMATSU', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '145.0'}, {'name': 'YOTAM BEN REUVEN', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '144.66'}, {'name': 'FILIP SCHENK', 'country': 'ITA', 'points': '143.0'}, {'name': 'CHUA DENNIS', 'country': 'SGP', 'points': '142.0'}, {'name': 'NATHANIEL COLEMAN', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '137.5'}, {'name': 'ADRIEN LEMAIRE', 'country': 'FRA', 'points': '126.5'}, {'name': 'ELLIS ERNSBERGER', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '112.5'}, {'name': 'PALMER LARSEN', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '103.0'}, {'name': 'NINO GRÜNENFELDER', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '100.0'}, {'name': 'JESSE GRUPPER', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '94.5'}, {'name': 'MARTIN BERGANT', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '89.5'}, {'name': 'CHEUNG-CHI SHOJI CHAN', 'country': 'HKG', 'points': '82.0'}, {'name': 'JULIEN CLÉMENCE', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '79.83'}, {'name': 'OSCAR BAUDRAND', 'country': 'CAN', 'points': '76.0'}, {'name': 'WILLIAM RIDAL', 'country': 'GBR', 'points': '69.5'}, {'name': 'YUFEI PAN', 'country': 'CHN', 'points': '62.5'}, {'name': 'MATIC KOTAR', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '57.5'}, {'name': 'ELIAS ARRIAGADA KRÜGER', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '57.0'}, {'name': 'HUALONG SONG', 'country': 'CHN', 'points': '56.0'}, {'name': 'HANNES VAN DUYSEN', 'country': 'BEL', 'points': '56.0'}, {'name': 'NILS FAVRE', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '52.23'}, {'name': 'ENEKO CARRETERO CRUZ', 'country': 'ESP', 'points': '52.0'}, {'name': 'TAISEI HOMMA', 'country': 'JPN', 'points': '46.0'}, {'name': 'DON VAN LAERE', 'country': 'NED', 'points': '43.83'}, {'name': 'RAM LEVIN', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '43.0'}, {'name': 'LUKA POTOCAR', 'country': 'SLO', 'points': '39.0'}, {'name': 'JAMES POPE', 'country': 'GBR', 'points': '39.0'}, {'name': 'CHRISTOPHER COSSER', 'country': 'RSA', 'points': '38.0'}, {'name': 'SUNGJOON CHAE', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '37.33'}, {'name': 'JIAHAO FU', 'country': 'CHN', 'points': '37.0'}, {'name': 'JOE GOODACRE', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '36.5'}, {'name': 'SHINYEONG YUN', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '33.33'}, {'name': 'CHIA HSIANG LIN', 'country': 'TPE', 'points': '30.0'}, {'name': 'LUKE GOH WEN BIN', 'country': 'SGP', 'points': '28.23'}, {'name': 'GEVA LEVIN', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '26.5'}, {'name': 'ILJA AUERSPERG', 'country': 'AUT', 'points': '25.5'}, {'name': 'HANNES PUMAN', 'country': 'SWE', 'points': '22.0'}, {'name': 'MINYOUNG LEE', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '20.83'}, {'name': 'WONWOO HAN', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '20.66'}, {'name': "MICHAEL O'NEILL", 'country': 'IRL', 'points': '20.56'}, {'name': 'LUCAS UCHIDA', 'country': 'CAN', 'points': '20.0'}, {'name': 'BENJAMIN VARGAS', 'country': 'CHI', 'points': '18.5'}, {'name': 'CIARÁN SCANLON', 'country': 'IRL', 'points': '18.5'}, {'name': 'MARCELLO BOMBARDI', 'country': 'ITA', 'points': '18.0'}, {'name': 'CARMEL RAZ ROMEO', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '17.0'}, {'name': 'FELIPE HO FOGANHOLO', 'country': 'BRA', 'points': '16.06'}, {'name': 'CHEUK-HEI HO', 'country': 'HKG', 'points': '16.0'}, {'name': 'FLORIAN KLINGLER', 'country': 'AUT', 'points': '16.0'}, {'name': 'ANTHONY GULLSTEN', 'country': 'FIN', 'points': '15.83'}, {'name': 'DOHYEON KIM', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '15.66'}, {'name': 'THILO JELDRIK SCHRÖTER', 'country': 'NOR', 'points': '15.5'}, {'name': 'FEDIR SAMOILOV', 'country': 'UKR', 'points': '14.0'}, {'name': 'ARDCH INTRACHUPONGSE', 'country': 'THA', 'points': '13.5'}, {'name': 'KA-CHUN YAU', 'country': 'HKG', 'points': '13.0'}, {'name': 'LIAM HEALY', 'country': 'AUS', 'points': '12.5'}, {'name': 'MARK BRAND', 'country': 'NED', 'points': '11.0'}, {'name': 'RODRIGO IASI HANADA', 'country': 'BRA', 'points': '10.0'}, {'name': 'ROMAN BATSENKO', 'country': 'UKR', 'points': '9.5'}, {'name': 'LUKE MUEHRING', 'country': 'USA', 'points': '9.4'}, {'name': 'SLAV KIROV', 'country': 'BUL', 'points': '9.0'}, {'name': 'MICHELE BONO', 'country': 'ITA', 'points': '9.0'}, {'name': 'RONNY ESCOBAR', 'country': 'CHI', 'points': '8.33'}, {'name': 'CALRIN CURTIS', 'country': 'RSA', 'points': '8.0'}, {'name': 'SERGII TOPISHKO', 'country': 'UKR', 'points': '8.0'}, {'name': 'YONGCHEN CHEN', 'country': 'CHN', 'points': '8.0'}, {'name': 'RADIN FOROUGHIAN', 'country': 'IRI', 'points': '7.5'}, {'name': 'CHI-FUNG AU', 'country': 'HKG', 'points': '7.5'}, {'name': 'MIKEL ASIER LINACISORO MOLINA', 'country': 'ESP', 'points': '7.0'}, {'name': 'MUHAMMAD FERZA FERNADA ABDI', 'country': 'INA', 'points': '7.0'}, {'name': 'MINSUNG HAN', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '7.0'}, {'name': 'SUNGHOON PARK', 'country': 'KOR', 'points': '7.0'}, {'name': 'MATEUS RODRIGUES BELLOTTO', 'country': 'BRA', 'points': '6.5'}, {'name': 'KIM MARSCHNER', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '6.0'}, {'name': 'PAUL BRAND', 'country': 'NED', 'points': '6.0'}, {'name': 'EMIL ABRAHAMSSON', 'country': 'SWE', 'points': '6.0'}, {'name': 'JOSÉ ALEJANDRO SAUCEDA RODRÍGUEZ', 'country': 'MEX', 'points': '5.66'}, {'name': 'PIETRO VIDI', 'country': 'ITA', 'points': '5.66'}, {'name': 'LASSE VON FREIER', 'country': 'GER', 'points': '5.5'}, {'name': 'BEN ABEL', 'country': 'AUS', 'points': '5.33'}, {'name': 'LUCAS PEDROZA DIAZ DE LEÓN', 'country': 'MEX', 'points': '5.0'}, {'name': 'AMIAD LIPMAN', 'country': 'ISR', 'points': '5.0'}, {'name': 'FRANZ JOSEF WEBER', 'country': 'MEX', 'points': '5.0'}, {'name': 'ALEJANDRO CRESPO COBOS', 'country': 'ESP', 'points': '5.0'}, {'name': 'NIMRÓD SEBESTYÉN TUSNÁDY', 'country': 'HUN', 'points': '4.66'}, {'name': 'DIEGO LEQUERICA BUSCAGLIA', 'country': 'PER', 'points': '4.0'}, {'name': 'KEVIN HEINIGER', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '4.0'}, {'name': 'PIOTR SCHAB', 'country': 'POL', 'points': '3.5'}, {'name': 'MAREK JELIGA', 'country': 'CZE', 'points': '3.0'}, {'name': 'PEDRO AVELAR', 'country': 'BRA', 'points': '3.0'}, {'name': 'KIPRAS BALTRUNAS', 'country': 'LTU', 'points': '3.0'}, {'name': 'CARLOS GRANJA', 'country': 'ECU', 'points': '2.66'}, {'name': 'TERENCE SARAMANDIF', 'country': 'MRI', 'points': '2.66'}, {'name': 'MARK SCANLON', 'country': 'IRL', 'points': '2.66'}, {'name': 'JORGE LOREDO DURAN', 'country': 'MEX', 'points': '2.0'}, {'name': 'YAN JAKOB', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '2.0'}, {'name': 'GERGŐ VÁLYI', 'country': 'HUN', 'points': '2.0'}, {'name': 'LEO KETIL BØE', 'country': 'NOR', 'points': '2.0'}, {'name': 'ZACH RICHARDSON', 'country': 'CAN', 'points': '2.0'}, {'name': 'LEONID OSADCHYI', 'country': 'UKR', 'points': '2.0'}, {'name': 'LOUIS GUIGNARD', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '1.0'}, {'name': 'PETER KURIC', 'country': 'SVK', 'points': '1.0'}, {'name': 'THEIS LINDEGREN ELFENBEIN', 'country': 'DEN', 'points': '1.0'}, {'name': 'FREDRIK SERLACHIUS', 'country': 'SWE', 'points': '1.0'}, {'name': 'ANTON YOUNG HONG NIELSEN', 'country': 'DEN', 'points': '1.0'}, {'name': 'PHILIPP GEISENHOFF', 'country': 'SUI', 'points': '1.0'}]
```

[image]

If you notice, the whole table information lies inside the iframe (with id="calendar"). So, we need to switch to this iframe first as you can see in the code above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about iframes or how they worked, but this has cleared a lot of things up for me!